# How to define DEPDIR in automake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, configure, automake

I am trying to find a way to define a path to .deps which stores the .Po files. I want it to be in obj instead of my src directory.

I am struggling in finding a way to define the path. I came to know that it is the DEPDIR which stores the path to .deps but where do I do it is unsure. Do we set it up in configure.ac or in Makefile.am;

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but my advice is not to waste your time fighting your tools. If you want to keep your source directory clean, set a separate build directory: `mkdir build && cd build && ../configure`.

Comment: Indeed, there is no supported way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not feasible with automake. You As ptomato suggested you should use an out-of-tree build if you don't want your source path to be "dirtied" by the build.